# Will existing subscriptions still be able to sync to a publisher that has had an article added to it (Merge Rep)

Tags: sql-server-2014, merge-replication

I have to add a new table to the publisher database which will then be added to the subscribers.
I have done some digging and to allow the table to be replicated I need to add it as an article for that publication.  When I add the article through the Articles under publication properties I receive the following message:

> After adding a new merge article, you must generate a new snapshot
> before changes from any subscription can be merged.
>
> Although a snapshot of all articles must be generated, only the
> snapshot of the new article will be used to synchronize existing
> subscriptions.
>
> Are you sure you want to add a new merge article?

I am planning on rolling out the changes tomorrow by generating a snapshot using the "Generate the selected snapshot now" option from the Data Partitions page of the publication properties.  This is then copied to the subscriber and the application we use will handle the rest of updating the subscriber database.

It is using SQL Server 2014, with merge replication.

Will the other subscribers still be able to sync their subscriptions before they have the new snapshot, or will they have to wait until they have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.
If you are adding a new article to an existing publisher you will need to rollout the snapshot before the subscriber is allowed to sync.